# Good IDE for C language with code-simplification-suggestions?

Tags: c, ide

I use `IntelliJ Idea CE` for `Java` and I like its features like it tells which of the declared parameters has never been used, simplification of code, auto-including libraries for methods selected from suggestions, etc.

Is there a `free` IDE for `C` language which can give me such kind of features. I need to mostly work with pointers. It will be good if the IDE tells me things like the pointer is never freed, etc.

I currently use `Visual Studio Code` on `Windows 10`. It doesn't suggest me functions from the libraries I haven't included.

Comment: Please don't forget to let us know which you choose, as that will help others who read this question in future. It is ok to post & accept your own answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Eclipse CDT](https://www.eclipse.org/cdt/) is a free C/C++ IDE which has a key combination (Ctrl+Shift+O, IIRC) which will remove unused `#include` and add those which are missing.

Most modern compilers (such as GCC) will warn you of unused parameters.

As a general topic, look at static code analysis tools, such as [Lint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lint_(software)) .

See also ([list of free static code analysis tools](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tools_for_static_code_analysis#C,_C++)).

I recommend the free [Splint](https://splint.org/), but there are many more

Comment: Thanks for answering, I have chosen CLion because I personally like JetBrains IDEs and I got it for free as I am a student.

Comment: I have to agree with you :-) JeytBrains are absolutely the best for IDEs. Anyone doing Python should use the their excelletnt, and free (even for commercial use) [PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/) community edition. Thank you for accepting my answer. You could also post & accept your own answer, if you don't just say "CLion", but list some great features. Don't forget that the debugger is your best friend. If you don't master that then you cannot call yourself a developer. Btw, Eclipse is the industry standard DIE for C/C++. If you code those at work, you ***will*** use it

Comment: CLion uses CMake as build tool; but CDT supports CMake, Make & GNU Autotools as build tool.